# Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.dll

Tags: c#, azure, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

> ---
>
> ### The use case:
>
> I made a simple UWP background application to retrieve temperature sensor data from a connected Raspberry-PI3 and set LED sensor blue or
>   red blinking depending on the value of MAX_TEMP.>
>   The PI3 runs on Windows 10 IoT Core (OS 10.0.17763107)
>   The UWP runs a background task at startup which reads on timed-intervals the values of the attached temperature sensor on the
>   PI3 and sets the connected LED sensors on the PI3 as appropriate
>   (depending if the read temperature value does not exceed the MAX_TEMP
>   value , if the current temperature value exceeds the MAX_VALUE then a
>   message is send to an IoTHub connected device on the cloud, some code
>   snipped:

// Read the value of the attached temperature sensor and turn it into a string

```
var sensorValue = _temperatureSensor.TemperatureInCelsius().ToString();

if (Double.Parse(sensorValue) > MAX_TEMP)
{
   // When MAX_TEMP exceeds, red led on, blue led off
   _ledRed.ChangeState(SensorStatus.On);
   _ledBlue.ChangeState(SensorStatus.Off);

   // Create event message to send to Azure IoT Hub ...
   var telemetryDataPoint = new
   {
      messageId = _messageId++,
      message = $"Max Allowed temperature exceeded !",
      deviceId = _deviceId,
      maxTemp = $"{MAX_TEMP}",
      temperature = sensorValue,
      ledRedState = $"{_ledRed.CurrentState}",
      ledBlueState = $"{_ledBlue.CurrentState}"
   };



// Create message to send to Cloud (IoTHub)
   var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
   var message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message     
   (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

   // Send to cloud ...
   **// This throws the exception as shown below !!!!!
   await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);**
```

}

```
Message thrown :
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
The thread 0xcd8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Thx for any response !

Kr,
Emmanuel Nuyttens

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/421

Comment: At last i could get it work by "downgrading" the "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client" Nuget package from v1.5.0. to v1.18.1